# Setting hardware breakpoint using winapi for current process

Tags: c, debugging, winapi

I want to set a breakpoint on my variable, when i do the read access, i have this code:

```
char * lpBuffer = NULL;

void proc(PVOID)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sleep(100);

        MessageBoxA(0, 0, 0, 0);
        char * h = lpBuffer;

        h[0x4] = 0x88;
    }
}

int main()
{
    lpBuffer = malloc(20);
    SetDebugPrivilege(TRUE);

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)proc, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);

    CONTEXT ctx = {};
    BOOL st = GetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
    ctx.Dr0 = (DWORD)&lpBuffer;
    ctx.Dr7 = 0x30002;
    st = SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

    ResumeThread(hThread);

    DEBUG_EVENT dbgEvent;

    int status = WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE);

    //..
}
```

I always get 0 from `int status = WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE);` it doesnt perfrorm any waiting  just returns 0 immediatly, i placed `MessageBoxA` to test, basically i don't get any notifications and waiting that the read has performed on `lpBuffer`. I think i have done something wrong, maybe it has to do with dr7 flags? 0x30002 is ‭00110000000000000010‬, so it should be hardware read/write bp.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681423.aspx) says: "*If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx).*" What does `GetLastError()` return? The documentation also says: "***Only the thread that created the process being debugged can call `WaitForDebugEvent`.***" So a process cannot debug itself. It can only be debugged by the process that spawned it (or by a process that calls `DebugActiveProcess()`).

Comment: Also, your `proc` function is declared wrong. It needs to be declared as `DWORD WINAPI proc(LPVOID)`, then you can get rid of the erroneous `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` type-cast when passing `proc` to `CreateThread()`.

Comment: __debugbreak() , __asm { int 3 }

Answer (score 0):

about debugging. for debug need create special ***DebugObject*** and associate process (which you want to debug) with this debug object. after this, when some events occur in process associated with debug object, system **suspend all threads in process**, insert debug event to debug object and set it to signal state. in debugger, thread which wait on debug object, say via `WaitForDebugEvent` (but possible direct pass handle of debug object to say `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`) awakened and handle this debug event. but if thread will be from debugged process - it will be suspended, as all threads in process and never handle this event. process hang in this case. so - process can not debug itself because system **suspend all threads in process** when debug event (exception for example) occur.

about `WaitForDebugEvent` doesnt perfrorm any waiting. `WaitForDebugEvent` internally call `ZwWaitForDebugEvent` and from where is `HANDLE hDebugObject` is geted ? from thread *TEB* (here exist special field for save it). when you call `CreateProcess` with flag `DEBUG_PROCESS` or `DebugActiveProcess` system internally call `DbgUiConnectToDbg` - this api check - are thread already have accosiated debug object (in *TEB*) and if yet no - create new with `ZwCreateDebugObject` and store it in *TEB* (it can be accessed via `DbgUiGetThreadDebugObject` and changed via `DbgUiSetThreadDebugObject`). only after this you can call `WaitForDebugEvent`. because you not direct create debug object via `ZwCreateDebugObject`, and not call `CreateProcess` with flag `DEBUG_PROCESS` or `DebugActiveProcess` - no debug objects assosiated with your thread, and call `WaitForDebugEvent` of course fail

only one option catch hardware breakpoint in own process - use *VEX*. for example:

```
LONG NTAPI OnVex(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo)
{
    WCHAR buf[1024], *sz = buf, wz[64];
    PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord = ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord;

    swprintf(wz, L"%x> %x at %p", GetCurrentThreadId(), ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode, ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);

    *buf = 0;

    if (ULONG NumberParameters = ExceptionRecord->NumberParameters)
    {
        sz += swprintf(sz, L"[ ");

        PULONG_PTR ExceptionInformation = ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation;
        do 
        {
            sz += swprintf(sz, L"%p, ", *ExceptionInformation++);
        } while (--NumberParameters);

        sz += swprintf(sz - 2, L" ]");
    }

    MessageBoxW(0, buf, wz, 0);

    return ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_SINGLE_STEP ? EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

DWORD HardwareTest(PVOID pv)
{
    WCHAR sz[64];
    swprintf(sz, L"hThread = %p\n", *(void**)pv);
    return MessageBoxW(0, 0, sz, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

void ep()
{
    if (PVOID handler = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, OnVex))
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, HardwareTest, &hThread, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0))
        {
            CONTEXT ctx = {};
            ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
            ctx.Dr3 = (ULONG_PTR)&hThread;
            ctx.Dr7 = 0xF0000040;

            SetThreadContext(hThread, &ctx);

            ResumeThread(hThread);

            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }

        RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(handler);
    }
}
```